# Generating list of modules from all .py files and installing without specifying module version

Tags: python, pip

I have hundreds of python files and I need to install all the existing modules, I thought I'd create a file with all the module names that are imported in the files:

```
import os

def remove_duplicates():
    lines = open('all_modules.txt', 'r').readlines()
    lines_set = set(lines)
    out  = open('all_modules.txt', 'w')
    for line in lines_set:
        out.write(line)

def main():
    fileDir = r"C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\tests vscode"
    fileExt = r".py"
    py_file_list = [_ for _ in os.listdir(fileDir) if _.endswith(fileExt)]

    with open('all_modules.txt', 'w+', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:

        for py_file in py_file_list:
            with open(py_file) as stacktest:
                stacktest_list = [line.strip() for line in stacktest.readlines()]

            for line in stacktest_list:
                if 'import ' in line and "'" not in line:
                    after_import = line.split('import ',1)[1]
                    before_space = after_import.split(' ')[0]
                    before_comma = before_space.split(',')[0]
                    f.write(before_comma + '\n')

    remove_duplicates()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example result in `all_modules.txt`:

```
pandas
time
dataframe_image
webbrowser
num2words
glob
Pool
schedule
move
csv
os
feedparser
```

But to install with pip install using `requirements.txt` it is necessary to have the version of the module I want to install, in this case, the computer is completely clean and I want the latest version of all modules.

Is there a way to install these modules at once without having to write one by one manually?

Comment: why not use cmd `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?

Comment: your approach won't work 100% reliably because the names in the `import` statements don't necessarily match the name of the package in PyPI, the package index for pip

Comment: "But to install with pip install using requirements.txt it is necessary to have the version of the module I want to install" ...that's not true, you can just try to `pip install -r all_modules.txt` ... it will try to install latest version of each, some may fail to be found due to name mis-match

Comment: Hi @shaikmoeed when I do this command, the list created has only 6 modules, many are missing, I don't know why.

Comment: Oh i see @Anentropic I didn't pay attention to this detail specified by you, I will do it that way, some will not actually install but it will solve the problem!

Comment: `pip freeze` will output the list of packages currently installed on your system. If you use virtualenv it will be just for the currently active virtualenv

Comment: If you want to have your own modules/packages, then use `setup.py` to create respective wheel files. And use them to install in any python environement.

Comment: Hi @Anentropic using the way you commented, I came across a two errors ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json``` Would you help me? It is a real module that manually installs correctly with ```pip install dataframe_image```

Comment: `json` does not need to be pip installed, it is part of python stdlib

Comment: @shaikmoeed in case I don't have any modules installed, it's a totally clean machine, so I'm looking for a way to easily grab all possible modules from the folder.

Comment: Really @Anentropic , my mistake when reading the terminal, I confused the fault position. Your indication worked perfectly for my need, if you want to create an answer with it so I can close the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But to install with pip install using requirements.txt it is necessary to have the version of the module I want to install

That's not true. You can take the file you have generated and run `pip install -r all_modules.txt`

Pip will go through each name in the file and attempt to install the latest version available (that might not be the same version you used when writing the code originally - things might not work, but it will at least install the package).

The other problems you will likely encounter are:

1. the names in your file are extracted from `import` statements, but the import name of a package does not necessarily match the name of the package in PyPI that you need to pip install
2. you will find some imported packages that do not need to be pip installed, such as packages from Python stdlib, or from other modules in your own project... these will give an error when you try to pip install them - or worse you may install a different package of the same name that exists in PyPI by coincidence